# ubuntu eric no module PyQt5.Qsci

Tags: python, qt, ubuntu, eric-ide

Just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS yesterday, installed Eric. Worked fine. Wanted to start Eric and use qtdesigner today, didn't work (got error qtdesigner not found) since you have to manually install it according to guides. Went through that now this error:

```
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/usr/share/eric/modules/Utilities/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
from PyQt5.Qsci import QSCINTILLA_VERSION_STR, QsciScintilla
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.Qsci'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/eric/modules/eric6.py", line 326, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/share/eric/modules/eric6.py", line 240, in main
import Preferences
File "/usr/share/eric/modules/Preferences/__init__.py", line 36, in  <module>
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import QWebSettings
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKit'
```

I already manually installed qscintilla, qt, pyqt, qtdesigner. What I have found is that under python3 there are distpackages containing pyqt4 and 5 (the ones missing according to the error) and I can import them when running python3 in the terminal. If I am running Python 2 that import isn't possible.
I am assuming that eric uses Python2 to start and thus does not find these packages?

I am very new to Linux and do not know if I am on the right track. I tried the solutions offered on the web, but the error just keeps coming up. Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Qt are you running for python2?...with `from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR`

Comment: this is what I get under Python:  from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     ImportError: No module named PyQt5.QtCore

Comment: hmm....then it seems you don't have PyQt5 installed for python2

Comment: That is what I was thinking as well. When I installed PyQt5 it did so for Python 3. According to another thread, they dropped it for Python 2. As I am new to Linux, I don't know how to build anything from source, as described in the thread here http://askubuntu.com/questions/662595/best-way-to-install-pyqt5-for-python-2-7-on-ubuntu-14-04[link]

Comment: I removed all the packages and installed them again. To no avail. It still says that pyqt5.qsci and qtwebkit are missing, even though they are present.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have this problem (ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.Qsci') and I solved it by these steps:

1. I opened the terminal and wrote this command: `pip3 install qscintilla`.
2. by above command my computer began to downloading qscintilla package, after downloading it start downloading pyqt5 and sip package.
3. after step 2 I wrote this command: `sudo apt-get remove eric`.
4. then I wrote this command: `sudo apt-get install eric`.
5. after above steps I run `eric` by typing: `eric` and pressed Enter; then my `eric` ran successfully.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the instructions on Eric's download pages, and make sure you use python3 while executing the *install.py* script.

From the Eric6 Technical Report

> Compatibility with Python ver. 3 or/and 2
>   From the current ver. 6, this same Eric IDE is fully Python 3 or/and 2 compatible, both considered
>   as an executing program and as a developing environment. Indeed this same unique Eric IDE can be
>   used with Python ver. 3 only, OR Python ver. 2 only, or Python ver. 3 AND ver. 2, together. This way
>   offering a unique environment where to attenuate the inconveniences caused by such odd
>   incompatibility between these two consecutive Python versions, and possibly easing the transition
>   between them.
>   That said, we have here decided to adopt and use Python ver. 3—and the consequently related
>   accessories, such as primarily the related PyQt library—as the only base language for this Report 1 , and
>   that for manifest reasons of manageability. Giving thus for granted that a fool-proof compatibility
>   should be experienced in case of adoption of Python ver. 2.